# How to make mat-expansion-panel cover the whole screen at expanded mode?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using multiple mat-expansion-panels on a single page.
I want the expanded panel to cover the whole screen even if it is located at the end of the screen.
It should come at the center of the page  and cover the whole area.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by overriding the default style of mat-expansion panel.
Add this style in your **styles.css** file,

```
.mat-expansion-panel-content > .mat-expansion-panel-body
 {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   height: 100vh;
    }
```

Here is a stack blitz working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8hvppy

Please add your work(code) next time.